# Time duration calculation Error runtime using VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am trying to calculate the time durations via the below `Sub`. But it takes only two iterations.where as it should take `4`, as a result all the durations are not being summed up.I introduced `2` `msgbox`- which are showing the result. Fitst one showing the length which is perfect,but the second one showing some thing undesired.

**CODE**

```
msgbox(ArrayListTaskDetails.Count) '~~ output is 16
For IndexSearch = 0 To ArrayListTaskDetails.Count - 1 Step 4

dt1 = ArrayListTaskDetails(IndexSearch + 3)         
SumDate = TimeAdd(dt1,SumDate)

If Err Then

msgbox(IndexSearch) '~~ output as 8. here is the question why the error occurs?
Err.Clear
Exit for

End If

Next

Function TimeAdd(dt1,dt2)

If (IsDate(Cdate(dt1)) And IsDate(Cdate(dt2))) = False Then ' `Type mismatch: Cdate` error occurs in this line. Could you guide me here where the wrong is?
TimeAdd = "00:00:00"
Exit Function
End If

TimeAdd = Hour(dt1)+Hour(dt2) & ":" & Minute(dt1)+Minute(dt2) & ":" & Second(dt1)+Second(dt2) 

End Function
```

***Note:*** Time duration are `00:05:23`,`00:11:58`,`195:33:12`,`320:37:13` respectively at 3,7,11,15 th position of the `List`

Comment: The issue still not resolved. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: What are you trying to do in your function?

Comment: @4M01 I want to add all the time durations and get them copied to another dictionary for future calculations, but it is not able to add the durations like `195:33:12,320:37:13`. Thus throwing error.

Comment: So basically yo need to check dt1 & dt2 are time values or not in first condition of function ?

Comment: Yes, you are right! But if I omit Cdate then also error comes that "Syntax error" .that probably for the values `00:05:23,00:11:58`. So anyway we would need to handle that!

Comment: Try to use function IsTime as given in below link, hope this will solve your problem http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21131/VBScript-IsTime-Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IsDate` function returns a Boolean value that indicates if the evaluated expression can be converted to a date. It returns True if the expression is a date or can be converted to a date; otherwise, it returns False.Link h[ere](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_isdate.asp)

Code  should be as :-

```
If Not (IsDate((dt1) And IsDate(dt2)) Then            '' If dt1 or dt2, any one from this id not date then it will set timeAdd = "00:00:00"
   TimeAdd = "00:00:00"
   Exit Function
End If
```

Comment: please see my `NOTE` in the description. If I don't use `CDate` then the summation gives me as `00:00:00` thus I used `Cdate`.After adding `Cdate`it gives me the ability to add till `00:05:23,00:11:58` after that the error is coming!